# When upgrading to Windows 10, do the three options in the "What to keep" prompt affect only the OS partition, or the entire hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, windows-10-upgrade

I have an OS partition (C) and a Data partition (D) with non-OS files. If I choose any of the three options, will this only affect the C: partition or will it reformat the entire physical drive, thus also removing the D partition?

Comment: Yes; It does.  If you have any doubts you should backup your data.

Comment: Source? Because it doesn't...

Comment: To understand my original comment.  I read "If I choose any of the three options, will this only affect the C: partition" and replied with the following statement.  Yes; It does.  I went on to indicate if you had any doubts you should back up your data.  I never attempted to indicate anything else.

Comment: Oh ok. I considered the second part ("... or will it reformat...") too and then a "Yes; it does." was a bit vague IMO, especially when getting it wrong would have serious consequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I took a plunge in the deep and selected "Nothing.", the harshest option. I assume the other two will behave the same way.

After the installation my partition was still there. So when upgrading, all three options will only affect the partition that has Windows already installed.

It is possible the drive letter will have changed because there might be other media attached (e.g. a USB stick). This can easily be fixed by unplugging said media and changing the drive letter in Disk Management (right-click the Start button).

I suggest caution if you have a multiple OS'es though.